# How can I make a function, whoch count the answer in a array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can sombody please help me !!!
I have an array

```
   frage1: "ja"
    frage2: "ja"
    frage3: "nein"
    frage4: "ja"
    frage5: "nein"
```

I would like to make an `onClick` function, which can count the number of all yes and no.
It should be only able to click on that button, if all questions have been answered.
please I need help !!!!

I am using react and the `useState` Hook to save the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should probably provide more Code.
However you can create a Loop or use a filter function to determine how often the Answer is yes / no.

```
/**
 * Let's expect the answer object is already filled out with your JSON Object
 */
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({
    question1: 'yes',
    question2: 'yes',
    question3: 'no',
    question4: 'yes',
    question5: 'no',
});

let yes = 0;
let no = 0;

answers.forEach(answer => {
    if (answer == 'yes') {
        yes++;
    }
    if (answer == 'no') {
        no++;
    }
})
```